# ActionBarCompat: How to set SearchItem Handler?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I add ActionBarCompat to my project based on [this](http://gmariotti.blogspot.de/2013/07/how-to-add-actionbarcompat-to-your.html) tutorial. But I get confused on how to give event for user input when search button is clicked.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ActionBar ab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setTitle("Test");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I found out that to get the input from user is with implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, as I found from [here](http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-action-views/). Don't forget to add this listener to the SearchView at onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method, likt this :

```
 @Override
```

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

return true;

}